# prepareForSegue fatal error swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to run my app but whenever I click of the button this error pops up: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" I know that this relates to my prepareForSegue function because when I take it out the app runs fine. I am trying to use the prepareForSegue function to retrieve variables and other things from my other view controller. Here is my code.

The hideBannerAds is a boolean.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?) {
    var FirstDest : View3 = segue.destinationViewController as View3

      if hideBannerAds == true {
            FirstDest.adBannerView2.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }
```

Comment: First thing, you should test which segue identifier is called, like that :          `if segue.identifier == "identifier_from_segue"
{...}`
Second, you should provide more code, will be easier to look around

Comment: It's never good to use the `as` operator, until you want your app to crash. You should use `as?` instead, if there's others segues to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?)
```

to

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject!)
```

By Looking at your code as Sid mentions you should also try

```
if segue.identifier == "name of segue " {
    var vc = segue.destinationViewController as View3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way would be:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "your_identifier_here"
    {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? View3{
            //Change your properties here
        }
    }
}
```

But inside of `prepareForSegue` you are trying to remove from the superview a view that it is not loaded yet. So You should set some property flag in View3 in order to know if the view should be loaded or not, and in the View3 viewDidLoad() remove (or avoid to load) your view based on this flag you have set.

Comment: This fixed one of my problems, but the app still crashes when I press my button. It still says the error. It also shows this error: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe).

Comment: You can not remove a view inside of prepareForSegue. Did you change that?

Comment: I used the code that you put up here and the error still appears.

Comment: You can't execute: FirstDest.adBannerView2.removeFromSuperview() inside of prepareForSegue().

Comment: Yes, so I put it inside if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? View3

Comment: You can not execute that line of code because the view is not loaded! You should change it to a boolean property and avoid to load adBannerView2 the viewDidLoad from the viewController.

Comment: Then where should I put this line of code. And how to I make the adBannerView2 disappear. I want it to disappear when hideBannerAds = true.

Comment: In View3 view controller you should take care to hide or not your view according to the boolean.

Comment: but I do not have the boolean in the View3 because it is in the ViewControlelr

Comment: That is part of the change you need to do in order to make it work as you want, because you can't remove a view from prepareForSegue.

Comment: How can I do that? How do I get the boolean hideBannerAds into View3? I know the problem is also in the prepareForSegue function without any code because when I take the code out it still crashes. This is what it says: 'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Dotcha_.View3 0x17298a00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key adBannerView.'